# Deleting the original content doesn't delete translated one

Tags: i18n-l10n, paragraphs

When I delete original content, the translated one isn't delete and I just can't delete it ("remove" button doesn't appears).

These are the steps to reproduce the issue.

- Install the Paragraphs module
- Create a *PARA-TEST* paragraph type with a single text field and unlimited values
- Create a *CONTENT-TEST* content type with *PARA-TEST* as unique field
- Create a new *CONTENT-TEST* node and insert some random value in the paragraph field, for example *test1*, *test2*, and *test3*
- Save and reopen it; click on *Translate*
- Replace the paragraph field values with *test1 - UK*, *test2 - UK*, and *test3 - UK*
- Save the translated node
- Reopen the original *CONTENT-TEST* node and delete a value from the paragraph field, for example *test3*
- Reopen the translated node and notice the *test3 - UK* value is still present.

I would expect *test3 - UK* were deleted from the translated node. Instead, *test3 - UK* is still present in the translated node and I can't remove it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bug reports should be filed on the modules issue queue on drupal.org

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  You've phrased this as a bug report which is likely to get the question closed.  I'd suggest rewriting the question to be about how to manage translated content within paragraphs so that deleting the original paragraph also deletes translations.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have configured the paragraph field correctly.

On the field settings page of the paragraph field you should see this warning

> Paragraphs fields do not support translation. See the [online documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2735121).

This means you should not check the box above this warning, that users may translate the field.

Instead make the paragraph type translatable and translate the field content of the paragraph.